# Why is the word "Honours" in plural form when used in "x Graduated with First Class Honours?"

Tags: phrases, grammatical-number

Is it because one has a lot of "honour**s**"?

Is "Graduated with First Class Honour<strike>s</strike>" common/acceptable?

(I'm not quite sure how to properly tag this question. Sorry about that.)

Comment: At least in the UK a decoration or medal like an OBE or knighthood is called an honour. Not sure why a degree equals multiple of those.

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on 'honours degrees', but doesn't explain why the term is in the plural. It's just the traditional terminology.

Comment: Honour Guard (more 'noncounty') but Honours Roll. No doubt the notion of plurality affects the form of the attributive noun. This is often, but not always, the case.

Comment: Local terms for local things like food, ceremonies, schools, etc. are always local. That is, the ones used in one place are different from (though they may resemble) the terms used in another place. Any group that has a tradition will preserve at least parts of that tradition, and local ways of talking about common things and events are one easy way to do that. As Kipling put it, _There are nine and sixty ways of constructing tribal lays, And every single one of them is right!_

Comment: @JohnLawler, the fact that such practices vary from place to place does not explain why they are what they are at a given place. The OP is asking why the word is in the plural, wherever it is in the plural.

Comment: At a given place, they have a given form and a given history. The history determines the form that is preserved, and the history is always different. Exactly like geography and speciation. In other words, word shapes in names are arbitrary. There are certainly reasons why it's plural in one place and singular in another, but they're lost in institutional tradition.

Comment: @JohnLawler, so the answer you are offering is that the reasons are lost, because the origins of the wording are too far in the past. That **may** in the end turn out to be the only answer that can be given, but one should not rush to it, until one has tried (or given time to other people to try) to find a more illuminating answer.

Comment: You'll find a different answer in every case. I'm really not trying to answer your question; it's too general and makes too many assumptions. Most questions here are due to improper assumptions.

Comment: The last edit is puzzling. The question, as formulated in the title, shows that you are well aware that the plural is common and acceptable, which makes it confusing that  you then proceed to ask whether it is common/acceptable. (Originally you asked whether the singular would be acceptable instead, and that is compatible with the rest of the question.)

Comment: @jsw29 Are you referring to my edit? The edit is still asking whether the singular one is acceptable. I struck out the s in "Honours" to highlight the difference. I now realize that it's not a wise choice. 
Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term is "[Honours Degree](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/honours-degree)" or "... with Honours". Making it singular would technically be incorrect, as it's not what the degree is called.

It's not clear where the phrase originates but a cursory search reveals that [early degree systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_degree#History) in Europe were a sort of apprenticeship with different ranks.

> At the university, doctoral training was a form of apprenticeship to a guild

The idea of a degree conferring a specific status to the bearer is also mentioned in [this document](https://www.postgraduate.study.cam.ac.uk/files/attachments/offer.pdf) from the University of Cambridge:

> A degree is a **state of grace** and as such, once you have been approved and conferred for one degree, you cannot have another degree of the same type approved and conferred on you again.

Finally, [some degrees](https://hls.harvard.edu/dept/registrar/diploma-information/diploma-translation-doctor-of-juridical-science-s-j-d/) have a variation of the following line:

> With all the rights, privileges and ***honors*** appertaining thereunto.

It's possible that the plural "honours" pertains to the status/state/rank of a degree holder, which confers privileges and rights. It would then makes sense for it to be plural in reference to the office of the degree holder and not the degree itself.

Comment: Most of this answer is about the consequences of having a degree (any degree), and it is indeed arguable that there may be a multiplicity of honours among these consequences. The question is, however, about different honours: those that are bestowed on some candidates in the course of getting the degree, and differentiate them from the recipients of the 'plain' version of the same degree.

Comment: @jsw29 can you point to a source discussing this difference?

Comment: My preceding comment was only an explication of what the question is about.